# typo3 formhandler error tx_formhandler_log

Tags: forms, typo3

I tried to implement a new form which creates a tt_addressrecord. But everytime when I submit the form it shows an error that the table tx_formhandler_log does not exist. But I use the standart ts. Here my ts for my form:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.newsletter {

    disableWrapInBaseClass = 1

    # Common configuration
    debug = 1
    name = Newsletter
    addErrorAnchors = 1
    1.templateFile = TEXT
    1.templateFile.value = typo3conf/templates/main/plugins/formhandler/newsletter.form.html
    langFile.1 = typo3conf/templates/main/plugins/formhandler/locallang.xml
    formValuesPrefix = notifiers
    disableWrapInBaseClass = 1
    isErrorMarker.default = error
    isErrorMarker {
        global = error
    }
    errorListTemplate {
        totalWrap >
        singleWrap = <p> | </p>
    }



    finishers {
        1.class = Tx_Finisher_DB
        1.config {
            table = tt_address
            key = uid
            fields {
                email.mapping = email
                email.ifIsEmpty = 1
                pid.ifIsEmpty = 109
                hidden.ifIsEmpty = 1
                module_sys_dmail_html.ifIsEmpty = 1
            }
        }
        2.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail
        2.config {
            checkBinaryCrLf = message
            admin {
                templateFile = TEXT
                templateFile.value = typo3conf/templates/main/plugins/formhandler/newsletter.email.admin.html
                sender_email = email
                to_email = {newsletter.mail.address.admin}
                replyto_email = email
                replyto_name = email
                subject = TEXT
                subject.value = {newsletter.subject.admin}
            }
        }
        3.class = Finisher_Redirect
        3.config {
            redirectPage = 1
            additionalParams {
                success = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which formhandler version are you using?

Comment: I use formhandler 2.0.1

Comment: can you access your database via phpmyadmin or equal and then check if the named table 'tx_formhandler_log' is available? if not, insert with the following sql: https://github.com/typo3-ter/formhandler/blob/master/ext_tables.sql

Answer (score 0):

A Database Compare could be helpful for your issue:

Go to the Install Tool -> Important Actions and click on `Database Compare`. This compares your current database to the configuration files and you can automatically fix missing tables or fields.

In older TYPO3 versions (< 6.2) you'll find this in menu item Database Analyser in the Install Tool.

Comment: I tried this several times but this table was not in the compare.